How to get part of nested JSON in QGIS expression
How to get part of nested JSON in QGIS expression? I create a magnetic declination from like this QGIS how to construct a declination diagram.
The return of NCEI (NGDC) online service would be a JSON. Now I get a preview like this:
{ 'model': 'WMM-2020', 'result': [ { 'date': 2024,7979, 'declination': 4,06194, 'declinatio… ], 'units': { 'declination': 'degrees', 'declination_sv': 'degrees', '… }, 'version': '0.5.1.11' } 

I only need the result declination with it´s value like here 4,06194 in a global/project variable. How to do this? Or must I render this json for every feature on my map (for symbology,rotation,angle...)? The value on magnetic delination will change form year to year, so it´s necessary to recalculate it periodically.

How do you load this information to qgis?

I create a function like Comrade Che said with the long script without the geom_to_wkt script. I call the getDeclination inside a variable and send my lat/lon values like getDeclination(61,69). Now I get this json.

I delete the line in the long function "  if name == 'main':
# example of use:
results = getDeclination(lat=61,
lon=69,
date=datetime.datetime.now())
print('\nThe results of the query are as follows:')
pprint.pprint(results)   "


I got the value... change the line return r.json... to "return r.json()["result"][0]["declination"]"
